# Type hint of Base class method based on Subclass

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, type-hinting

When creating a base class with a request method that will be exactly the same for all subclasses. There does not seem to be an easy way of having separate type-hints based on which subclass made the request.

The example below is how I currently am solving this issue, but it seems as if there is a better way.

```
class Response(TypeDict): ...

class FooResponse(Response): ...

class BarResponse(Response): ...

class Request:

    @classmethod
    def make_request(cls, args: Any) -> Response:
        # This will return a dict response based on cls.TYPE (if cls.TYPE == Foo, FooResponse will be returned)
        return execute_db_query(cls, args)


class FooRequest(Request):

    @classmethod
    def make_request(cls, args: Any) -> FooResponse:
        return FooResponse(**super().make_request(cls, args))


class BarRequest(Request):

    @classmethod
    def make_request(cls, args: Any) -> BarResponse:
        return BarResponse(**super().make_request(cls, args))
```

Is there a better way of doing this, either by specifying Response type on the subclass or by just overriding the method signature and no the functionality?

Something like (I know this does not work):

```
class FooRequest(Request):
    @classmethod
    def make_request(...) -> FooResponse: ...
```

I would assume that using something like Generic[T] and TypeVar() could be a way to go?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `typing.overload` is what you seek.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import overload

class Request:
    @overload
    @classmethod
    def make_request(cls: FooRequest, args: Any) -> FooResponse: ...
    @overload
    @classmethod
    def make_request(cls: BarRequest, args: Any) -> BarResponse: ...
    
    def make_request(cls, args):
        return actual_implementation(cls, args)
```

Now your `FooRequest` and `BarRequest` no longer need to supply their implementation of (or type hints for) `make_request`.

---

If on the other hand your only goal is to type hint the IDE, you could:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar


class Response: ...
class FooResponse(Response): ...
class BarResponse(Response): ...

T = TypeVar('T', bound=Response, covariant=True)

class Request:
    @classmethod
    def make_request(cls: Request, args: Any) -> T: 
          return actual_implementation(cls, args


class FooRequest(Request):
    @classmethod
    def make_request(cls: FooRequest, args: Any) -> FooResponse:
          return super(FooRequest, cls).make_request(args)
```

This would make the IDE accept

```
fooresponse: FooResponse = FooRequest.make_request(None)
```

but reject

```
fooresponse: FooResponse = Request.make_request(None)
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this more dynamically? Imagine having 10 subclasses, then you'd have a very long list of overloads cluttering the base class

Comment: Dynamically, no. In any case your `actual_implementation` will need to have case management to return different types. Otherwise you could say that the base method returns a covariant type T upper bound to the base response, but I can't really imagine a use case to come up with MRE.

Comment: Actually, during runtime, all responses are of type Dict and the types are indistinguishable  from each other. TypeDict are only used for type-hints, as you probably already know. I don't think I understood your second statement about covariant type.

Comment: check the edit, maybe that's closer to your usecase if you're only concerned about IDE hinting. ps: you could drop the covariant `TypeVar` altogether and just have the base method return `Response`